# How i can change column parameter of existing row in datatable?

Tags: winforms, sqlite

I edited my question but it still close without response. So i took advise from messagebox and open another question with more information.

I had table in my librarian database app on Windows Form, And one of columns include parameter "amount'. How can i correctly increase it if there consilience in all other columns in addrow SQLcommand?

Here code:

```
        private void ConfimAddBookButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conString = "Data Source=Books.db;Version=3;";
            string name = AddBookNameTextBox.Text;
            string author = AddBookAuthorTextBox.Text;
            string genre = AddBookGenreTextBox.Text;
            int amount = 1;
            string SQLiteExpression = "insert into Books (BookName, AuthorName, Genre, Amount) values (@name, @author, @genre, @amount)";
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(conString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQLiteExpression, connection);
                SQLiteParameter nameParam = new SQLiteParameter("@name", name);
                SQLiteParameter authorParam = new SQLiteParameter("@author", author);
                SQLiteParameter genreParam = new SQLiteParameter("@genre", genre);
                SQLiteParameter amountParam = new SQLiteParameter("@amount", amount);
                command.Parameters.Add(nameParam); command.Parameters.Add(authorParam); command.Parameters.Add(genreParam); command.Parameters.Add(amountParam);
                int number = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Book sucsessfuly added");
                this.Close();
            }
```

As you can see. The row will be always added with amount equal 1. And i needed to increase amount in the exsisted row if other parameters are consilience.

UPD. I found solution for latest problem:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Books (Bookname, AuthorName, Genre, amount) VALUES ( @name, @author, @genre, @amount)....
```

As you can see, for saving progress after closing a program, i needed add name of columns after "Books".

Comment: Do you want to update a row in the database (ie increase amount) if the row already exists in the database?

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus yes. You understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to :

- insert a row if there not already a row with the same `BookName`, `AuthorName` and `Genre`
- otherwise update the existing row by increasing the amount by the specified value

If your version of SQLite is newer than 3.24.0, you can use an [UPSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html)

You need first to create a unique constraints on what define an *existing row*

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniquebook ON Books(BookName, AuthorName, Genre);
```

You can then use queries like :

```
INSERT INTO Books (BookName, AuthorName, Genre, Amount)
VALUES (@name, @author, @genre, @amount)
ON CONFLIT(Bookname, AuthorName, Genre)
DO UPDATE SET amount = amount + @amount
```

Edit :
With older version of SQlite :

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Books (BookName, AuthorName, Genre, Amount)
VALUES (
  @name,
  @author,
  @genre,
  COALESCE((SELECT Amount FROM Books WHERE BookName = @name and AuthorName = @author AND Genre = @genre), 0) + @amount
);
```

In this case the unique index is not mandatory (but still recommended for performance and data consistency reason)

Comment: i have a error:
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
near "CONFLIT": syntax error'
I added script in Book.db:
-- Script Date: 02.06.2020 15:45  - ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting version 3.5.2.86
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [Books_uniquebook] ON [Books] ([BookName] ASC,[AuthorName] ASC,[Genre] ASC);

And edited string SQLiteExpression in code as you show:
 ...ON CONFLIT(Bookname, AuthorName, Genre) DO UPDATE SET Amount ="+amount+" + @amount";

Comment: It seems that the version of SQLite you are using is older than 2018. I will edit the answer

Comment: Well. Now i had another error:
**SQL logic errortable Books has 5 columns but 4 values were supplied**. By the way i download the last version from offical website. It was pretty hard for me to understand wich version i needed. So i probably download some old one.
And may i ask another question? If answer is yes, here it is:
As i understand my parameters does't contain "value" and all added rows did not saving after closing the app. How can i fix that problem?

Comment: strange, this error happen when the target columns are not specified but this is not the case here

Comment: Another solution is to use 2 queries : first update, check the update count (the number returned by `ExecuteNonQuery`), if it is 0 then insert

Comment: Thanks, I will try.. By the way the problem in first place was'nt an old version. It was a syntax error T_T.
> CONFLIT
conflict man T_T

Comment: i found solution for both problem! II will upload it in the question.